# Make draggable elements not to pass left and top borders

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag

I have one `#mainDiv` with draggable `.foo` tables in it. How can I make these `.foo` tables not to leave their parent div from left and top sides? Is there a way to set Containment for left and top borders only? See the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/3bc6mm7b/

(Drag and drop any `item` to the right and drag it outside the container to see the problem)

Another solution for this problem would be if the user could scroll the content even if they drag the table beyond left and top borders.

```js
$('#deviceName li').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: 'invalid'
            });
            $('#interface li').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: 'invalid'
            });
            $('#display li').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: 'invalid'
            });
            $('#output li').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: 'invalid'
            });
            function foo(){
                $('.foo').each(function() {
                    $(this).draggable({
                        //containment: $(this).parent(),
                        stack: '.foo'
                    });
                });
            }
            var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
            $('#mainDiv').droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
                        var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
                        var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
                        var item = $('<table class="foo elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="'+(fooCount+1)+'"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass">' + title + '</th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
                        $(this).append(item);
                        fooCount += 1;
                        foo();
                    }
                }
            });
            
            var ListCount = $('.tableConn').length;
            $("body").on('click', '.addList', function(){
                var newtr = '<tr class="tableBody" id="'+ListCount+'_'+ListCount+'"><td class="tableConn">Link '+(ListCount+1)+'</td></tr>';
                ListCount += 1;
                $(newtr).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent());
                addPoints();
                
            });

            function addPoints(){
                jsPlumb.setContainer("mainDiv");
                jsPlumb.draggable($('.foo'));
                $('.tableBody').each(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('jsplumb-endpoint-anchor')){
                        var objId = $(this).attr("id");
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), {
                            anchor: "Right",
                            isSource:true,
                            isTarget:false,
                            connector:"Bezier",
                            endpoint: ["Image", {
                                url: "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png",
                                width: 17,
                                height: 17
                            }],
                            connectorOverlays:[ 
         [ "Arrow", { width:10, height: 10, length:10, location:0.97, id:"arrow", foldback: 0.8} ]
        ],
                            connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"grey", lineWidth:3 },
                            connectorHoverStyle:{ lineWidth:3 },
                            maxConnections: -1,
                            uuid: $(this).attr("id")+'r'
                        });
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), {
                            anchor: "Left",
                            isSource:false,
                            isTarget:true,
                            connector:"Bezier",
                            endpoint: ["Image", {
                                url: "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png",
                                width: 17,
                                height: 17
                            }],
                            connectorOverlays:[ 
         [ "Arrow", { width:10, height: 10, length:10, location:0.97, id:"arrow", foldback: 0.8} ]
        ],
                            connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"grey", lineWidth:3 },
                            connectorHoverStyle:{ lineWidth:3 },
                            uuid: $(this).attr("id")+'l'
                        });
                        jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), {
                            anchor: "Top",
                            isSource:false,
                            isTarget:true,
                            connector:"Bezier",
                            endpoint: ["Image", {
                                url: "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png",
                                width: 17,
                                height: 17
                            }],
                            connectorOverlays:[ 
         [ "Arrow", { width:10, height: 10, length:10, location:0.97, id:"arrow", foldback: 0.8} ]
        ],
                            connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"grey", lineWidth:3 },
                            connectorHoverStyle:{ lineWidth:3 },
                            uuid: $(this).attr("id")+'l'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#leftDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
}

#deviceInfo {
    min-height: auto;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 3px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

#menu li span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    cursor: move;
}

#menu li ul li:first-child {
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

#settingsDiv {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#mainDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 85%;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 3px;
}

.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}

.thClass {
    display: block;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.addList{
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.addList:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: antiquewhite;
}

.devInfo {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.1.8/jsPlumb.js"></script>
    <style>
        .jsplumb-endpoint {
            z-index: 10;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <div id="deviceInfo">
            <ul id="menu">
            <li>Device Name
                <ul id="deviceName">
                    <li>
                      item 1
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Interface
                <ul id="interface">
                    <li>
                      item 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Display
                <ul id="display">
                    <li>
                      item 3
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Output
                <ul id="output">
                    <li>
                      item 4
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="settingsDiv">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        
    </div>
```